# Change all color on the screen without defining view

Tags: java, android, pdf, screen, systemcolors

#### Reading pdf file issue, again!

---

I'm developing a book reader which opens pdf files. It is a well known issue that working with pdf can be so demanding for Android developers.

---

My question is also based on this problem. I've investigated many sites blogs but couldn't find any solution to change the textcolor of pdf file, finally I thought that we can change the original screen colors, for example changing black to white and white to black, in a nutshell, making colors contrast.

[image: Black]
[image: White]

---

Any suggestion will be welcome. Please help me to solve this problem.

---

The code that I use to open pdf file is:

```js
pdfView.fromAsset("pdf.pdf")
                .pages(0) // all pages are displayed by default
                .enableSwipe(true) // allows to block changing pages using swipe
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .enableDoubletap(true)
                .defaultPage(0)
                // allows to draw something on the current page, usually visible in the middle of the screen
                .onDraw(new OnDrawListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLayerDrawn(Canvas canvas, float pageWidth, float pageHeight, int displayedPage) {

                    }
                })
                // allows to draw something on all pages, separately for every page. Called only for visible pages
                .onDrawAll(new OnDrawListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLayerDrawn(Canvas canvas, float pageWidth, float pageHeight, int displayedPage) {

                    }
                })
                .onLoad(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {

                    }
                }) // called after document is loaded and starts to be rendered
                .onPageChange(new OnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {

                    }
                })
                .onPageScroll(new OnPageScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrolled(int page, float positionOffset) {

                    }
                })
                .onError(new OnErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable t) {

                    }
                })
                .onRender(new OnRenderListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitiallyRendered(int nbPages, float pageWidth, float pageHeight) {

                        pdfView.fitToWidth();

                    }
                }) // called after document is rendered for the first time
                .enableAnnotationRendering(false) // render annotations (such as comments, colors or forms)
                .password(null)
                .scrollHandle(null)
                .enableAntialiasing(true) // improve rendering a little bit on low-res screens
                // spacing between pages in dp. To define spacing color, set view background
                .spacing(0)
                .load();
```

The library that I used:

```
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.7.0-beta.1'
```

Thanks in advance.